# How can I reinitialize ngMaps when changing routes in Angular, using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I'm using [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) and here's my relevant code:

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" map-lazy-load-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}" ng-style="{'height': feedActualHeight + 'px'}">
        <ng-map id="iPadFeedMap" zoom="14" center="Times Square, New York, NY">
        </ng-map>
      </div>
```

This works great and loads the map perfectly. But when I navigate away and then come back to the page, the map is grayed out:
[image]

Is there a way to re-initialize the map when this page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it only occurs in case when value for `center` attribute is provided as *address* value (e.g. `Times Square, New York, NY`). In that case the way the map center is determined consist of the following steps:

- since [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) leverages [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#geocoding), the corresponding method is invoked to resolve actual location (`lat,lng`)
- Map object `center` property is getting updated

Since this issue never occurred for me when center attribute is provided as location value (e.g. `[40.759011, -73.98447220000003]`) i propose to change the way how map is initialized:

- remove setting of `center` attribute `center="Times Square, New
  York,NY"`
- instead set map center as demonstrated below:

Example: set map center by address

```
NgMap.getMap("iPadFeedMap").then(function (map) {
     NgMap.getGeoLocation($scope.address)
     .then(function (latlng) {
            map.setCenter(latlng);
     });
});
$scope.address = "Times Square, New York, NY";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/x7oq8qLg/)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the exact same issue regardless of how `center` was being set (it failed both with lat/lng and a physical address), but the accepted answer wasn't quite working for me.

My solution was to use NgMap's `lazy-init` property to re-initialize the map each time I returned to it.

```
<ng-map id="dashboard-map"
        center="Boston, MA"
        lazy-init="true"
        zoom="9"
        map-type-id="TERRAIN">
</ng-map>
```

In my `ctrl` I used the following code to 1) find the uninitialized map in the DOM and 2) initialize it

```
// dashboardCtrl.js

NgMap.getMap({ id: "dashboard-map" }).
  then(function(map) {
    NgMap.initMap(map.id);
  });
```

This way every time I hit my dashboard, the ctrl would run and re-init the map. It now shows properly every time.

This was a helpful thread to read through: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/387